# Mootools FormCheck - Making a field required when a checkbox is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I am using mootools formcheck and I have a function called when a checkbox is checked:

```
    function dnb_check(){

    if (document.getElementById("DNB").checked){
        var segments = new Element('input', {
            class   : "validate['required']",
            name    : "segments",
            id      : "segments"
        }).inject('third_party');
        formcheck.register($('segments, 0'));

    }
    else{
    formcheck.dispose($('segments'));
    }
    }
```

This is adding an input element to the end. I tried messing with the number at the end but it keeps adding it at the end no matter what. All I want to do is make an existing input box have: class="['required'] so it will check this input box when a certain checkbox is checked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first - `class` is a registered keyword that IE won't let you use, even as a property of an object. you need to use `"class"`.

Or in mootools 1.3+ you can use the slick constructor:

```
new Element('input#segments[name=segments][class=validate[\'required\']]').inject(document.body); 

// for normal classes (not meant to be for json!)
new Element('input#foo.bar[required]'); // will add <input id=foo class=bar required />
```

second, you save a reference to the element in `var segments` then go through the DOM to get the element again? you should be able to pass `formcheck.register(segments, nn);` - as per the example. http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html#FormCheck.register - you are mixing the argument to the selector with the second argument of the register method.

this should not be tagged `jquery` either.

Comment: When I used formcheck.register it creates a whole new input as per my initial comment. This would be fine if it created it in the right location but the location parameter doesn't work. I can't get the code you provided to inject [class=validate[\'required\']]. Do you mind guiding me a bit more?

Comment: I got the classes to change with simple javascript, but formcheck doesn't scan through the new classes that were added on submit and doesn't check it at all. ANy thoughts?    if (document.getElementById("DNB").checked){
document.getElementById("segments").className = "validate['required','%segments']";
}
else
document.getElementById("segments").className = "dummy";
}